# GWT - RPC equivalent of "ServiceLayerDecorator.invoke(Method domainMethod, Object... args)"

Tags: java, servlets, gwt, rpc, requestfactory

For Request factory calls I can use `ServiceLayerDecorator.invoke(Method domainMethod, Object... args)` to check for every method that is invoked, if the user has a valid session and is allowed to access the method. What is the equivalent for RPC calls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could override AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.onAfterRequestDeserialized(RPCRequest)

```java
/**
 * Override this method to examine the deserialized version of the request
 * before the call to the servlet method is made. The default implementation
 * does nothing and need not be called by subclasses.
 * 
 * @param rpcRequest
 */
protected void onAfterRequestDeserialized(RPCRequest rpcRequest) {
}
```

for your servlets. Maybe create a central `MyBaseRemoteServiceServlet`, where you override the method, and then derive all your remote service servlets from that. The `RPCRequest` should contain all the info you need, including the method that was called, and its parameters.